# Set the UIButtons size according to iPhone 4,5,6 and 6 plus

Tags: iphone, ios8

Using Adaptive layouts for iOS 8 in Xcode 6 and using storyboard. Trying to update the button size and it's x,y according to the device. It's working fine in iPhone 4 and 5, but in 6 and 6 plus it distorts. Below are the screenshots attached.
Please guide how to make it similar to as in iPhone 4 and iPhone 5.

[image]

[image]

iphone 4 image
iphone 6 image

how to make both similar as per their respective devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this in Interface Builder, select rectangles 1-6, check "Equal Widths" and "Equal Heights", and then add the constraints.

[image]

**Edit:** For a tutorial on auto-layout, you can check out: [Beginning Auto Layout Tutorial in iOS 7](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Comment: No, I am doing with the storyboards. Will it work there?

Comment: @iPhone6 Yes, it will. Select all the rectangles by SHIFT+clicking them and then set Equal Widths/Heights as in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes it is thanks a lot. Can you guide me some tutorial from where i can learn these things. I have already googled a lot serpent a day already, but still faced issues like this.

Comment: @iPhone6 Added as an edit to my answer. Definitely takes some time to get used to. It's worth it in the end though! 